# interpolation - r approx() returns NA when using xout option

Tags: r

here's my data, representing reflectance observed at each wavelength (wl):

```
wl <- c(442.7, 492.4, 559.8, 664.6, 704.1, 740.5, 782.8, 832.8, 864.7, 945.1, 1613.7, 2202.4)
pt_1 <- c(0.024, 0.0265, 0.0575, 0.0457, 0.1003, 0.2672, 0.3447, 0.3732, 0.3814, 0.3739, 0.1704, 0.0907)
pt_2 <- c(0.0234, 279, 57,   0.0454, .0963, .2642, 3446, .365, 0.3864, .3919, .1726, 0.0884) 
mydata <- data.frame(wl, pt_1, pt_2)
```

this does what I expect if not completely what I want, returning a df with interpolated values for all columns:

```
interp <- as.data.frame(apply(mydata, 2, function(x) approx(x, y = NULL, method = "linear", n = 20)$y))
```

I want to specify the `xout` values (as per my understanding of `?approx`):

```
interp1 <- as.data.frame(apply(mydata, 2, function(x) approx(x, y = NULL, method = "linear", xout = c(450, 550, 670, 700, 704, 706, 740.5, 750, 950, 1510))$y)) #
```

but this produces NAs only. Can anyone see my error?

even better, I would like to keep the original wavelengths by defining them in `xout`:

```
wl_orig <- as.vector(mydata$wl)
interp1 <- as.data.frame(apply(mydata, 2, function(x) approx(x, y = NULL, method = "linear", xout = c(wl_orig, 450, 550, 670, 700, 704, 706, 740.5, 750, 950, 1510))$y)) #
```

Comment: Your `xout` is way too huge: Since `y` is not passed into the function, the `wl` acts as the response and the indices acts as the `predictor` therefore, xout can take values between 1 and 12 or something closer to the `length(wl)` beyond which the extrapolation will completely fail.

Comment: thanks @Onyambu. According to the docs, `xout` is "an optional set of values specifying where interpolation is to take place". To me that says value(s) of `x` where I want to know `y`. Or have I got this wrong? Need I pass `y`? If so idk how to as I am applying across columns. Could you perhaps provide a working example?

Comment: If you do not pass y, then your literraly passing the points (1,442.7), (2, 492.4),  (3,...) etc. Showing tgat x=1,2,3,4... while y =442.7, 492.4 ... now you will note that x=1:12. Your xout has values >400. It is not logical to extrapolate 400 from 12. You could do xout=(13,14,15,20) to see the extrapolation. Ie will definitely not be NA since these values are close to 12